# Añadir varios replace a la vez para la primera columna

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Necesito ayuda. He probado varias opciones y no funciona. Tengo este código, el cual elimina las celdas con espacios vacíos de la primera columna, utilizando `replace` y `setvalue`. Ahora quiero añadir más sustituciones para la misma columna, por ejemplo comas (,) por barra diagonal(/), pero al añadir el código `var reemplazarComas = sheet.getRange(i+2,1).setValue(comas);` no hace nada, ni siquiera para lo de espacios vacíos.
¿Cómo debo ponerlo para que haga a la vez todas las sustituciones que quiero añadir? Gracias.

```
  function reemPlazar() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("BBDD");
  var getLastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = ss.getRange("A2:A" + getLastRow ).getValues();
  for (var i = 0 ; i<range.length ; i++) {
  var vacios = range[i].toString().replace(/ /g, "");
  var comas = range[i].toString().replace(",", "/");
  var eliminarEspacios = sheet.getRange(i+2,1).setValue(vacios)
  var reemplazarComas = sheet.getRange(i+2,1).setValue(comas);
  }
```

[image: eliminar espacios vacios y sustituciones]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que el código no hace nada porque

1. se tienen dos líneas que estan replazando valores del mismo dato original (`range[i]`)

   ```
   var vacios = range[i].toString().replace(/ /g, ""); 
   var comas = range[i].toString().replace(",", "/");
   ```
2. se tienen dos líneas escribiendo diferentes valores en la misma celda

   ```
   var eliminarEspacios = sheet.getRange(i+2,1).setValue(vacios)
   var reemplazarComas = sheet.getRange(i+2,1).setValue(comas);
   ```

Una manera de lograr lo que estas buscando es que "encadenes" los `replace`.

```
var valor = range[i].toString()
   .replace(/ /g, "")
   .replace(/,/g, "/")
sheet.getRange(i+2,1).setValue(valor)
```

NOTAS:

1. En primer parámetro del segundo `replace` se usó una expresión regular con el modificar `g` en lugar de una cadena de texto, para que se reemplacen todas las comas.
2. No es necesario declarar una variable si no vas a hacer nada con el rango al que estas asignado el valor.
3. Si quieres optimizar el tiempo de ejecución del código, en lugar de escribir en la hoja de cálculo en cada iteración del `for` es mejor que pases los datos a un Array y después del `for` pases todos los valores en una sólo llamada

```
function reemPlazar() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("BBDD");
  var getLastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = ss.getRange("A2:A" + getLastRow ).getValues();
  var valores = []; // Inicializar el Array donde pondremos los valores corresponsientes a cada celda
  for (var i = 0 ; i<range.length ; i++) {
   var valor = range[i].toString()
       .replace(/ /g, "")
       .replace(/,/g, "/");
   valores.push([valor]); // Agregar un Array con un valor que corresponde a una fila con una celda.
  }
  sheet.getRange(2,1,valores.length,1).setValues(valores);
}
```